# How do I set up the latest version of work items in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs

How to set up the latest version of items to be downloaded on check out in TFS 2010? I use VS 2010 to connect to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to Tools – Options.

In Source control options, browse to Visual Studio Team Foundation server options. You can check “Get latest version of item on check out” box there.